# Conditional JOIN between tables?

Tags: sql, join, conditional-statements

I have two table and I should write a select query which join this two table but I do not know what is conditional join between this two tables?

**Can some body say what is?**

```sql
TABLE ParameterRegistration
(
    RegistrationTime DATETIME,
    PatiNo VARCHAR(12),
    Source VARCHAR(64),
    Code VARCHAR(64),
    NameOfCodingSystem VARCHAR(64) NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(64),
    ValueType CHAR(2) NULL,
    NumericValue INT NULL,
    StringValue VARCHAR(64) NULL,
    TextValue TEXT NULL,
    Unit VARCHAR(64) NULL,
    UnitCode VARCHAR(64) NULL,
    UnitCodingSystem VARCHAR(64) NULL,
    Remark VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    CreateDate DATETIME,
    CreateUserId T_USER_ID
)
```

**and**

```sql
TABLE External
(
    ModDate DATETIME,
    ModUserId VARCHAR(12),
    UbMem VARCHAR(64),
    Code VARCHAR(64),
    Name VARCHAR(64),
    Service VARCHAR(64),
    NameOfCodingSystem VARCHAR(64) NULL,

)
```

Comment: Why can't you use `... FROM TABLE1 JOIN TABLE2 ON condition`?

Comment: How are the tables related?  What fields exist in both tables that allow you to join them together?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171788/sql-conditional-join

Comment: NameOfCodingSystem, Name and Code columns exist in both table

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM ParameterRegistration NATURAL JOIN External;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When joining tables you have to join on fields that are related.  Since you did not provide a lot of information it looks like you have 3 fields that possibly could be joined on.

- NameOfCodingSystem VARCHAR(64)
- Name VARCHAR(64)
- Code VARCHAR(64)

So you could technically write your query one of these ways:

```
SELECT *
FROM ParameterRegistration P
INNER JOIN External E -- or LEFT JOIN, etc
ON P.NameOfCodingSystem = E.NameOfCodingSystem
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM ParameterRegistration P
INNER JOIN External E -- or LEFT JOIN, etc
ON P.Name = E.Name
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM ParameterRegistration P
INNER JOIN External E -- or LEFT JOIN, etc
ON P.Code = E.Code
```

OR you can join on all of the fields at the same time

```
SELECT *
FROM ParameterRegistration P
INNER JOIN External E -- or LEFT JOIN, etc
ON P.NameOfCodingSystem = E.NameOfCodingSystem  AND
P.Name = E.Name AND
P.Code = E.Code
```

My suggestion would be to study up on `JOINs`.  Here are some resources but there are plenty on the internet:

- [A Visual Explanation of Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)
- [SQL Joins](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/joins.php)
- [Joins](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-JOIN.asp)

Answer (score 3):

You can only properly join those two tables if they have a relation of some kind.

Check [THIS ARTICLE](http://www.functionx.com/sql/Lesson11.htm) for some info.

---

Assuming that in your case, the tables are related with the columns Code, NameOfCodingSystem and Name you can make a join like this:

```
select p.*, e.* from ParameterRegistration p
inner join External e on p.Code = e.Code and
                         p.NameOfCodingSystem = e.NameOfCodingSystem and
                         p.Name = e.Name
```

Comment: If you look at the both table you can see relation between them. look at table column name please.

Comment: @itro, that's why I've answered with a sql query as well.